# I cannot figure out why my code returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I've tried to solve the given challenge.

I cannot find a problem why my code does not return a value.

Given an array of integers, find the one that appears an odd number of times.

There will always be only one integer that appears an odd number of times.

input : [ 20, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4, 20, 4, -1, -2, 5 ]

```js
function findOdd(array) {
  let answer
  for (let i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
        let counter = 0;
        const value = array[i]
        
        for(let k = 0; k < array.lengh; k++){
           if( value == array[k]){
              counter++
           }
          if(counter % 2 !== 0){
              answer = value;
          }
    }
  }
  return answer
}

 console.log(findOdd([ 20, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4, 20, 4, -1, -2, 5 ]));
```

Comment: Have you tried walking through the code with a debugger?

Answer (score 4):

It's because you misspelled `length` as `lengh`. Change `for(let k = 0; k < array.lengh; k++){` to `for(let k = 0; k < array.length; k++){`.

Please note that even if you correct it, your code still doesn't do what you want, it will still fail to find a number that occurs odd number of times in specific inputs.

Here is a code I wrote that should help you achieve what you want:

```js
function findOdd(array) {
  let occurences = {};

  array.forEach(num => {
    if (!occurences.hasOwnProperty(num)) {
      occurences[num] = 1;
    } else {
      occurences[num] += 1;
    }
  })

  for (let key in occurences) {
    if (occurences.hasOwnProperty(key) && occurences[key] % 2 == 1) {
      return key;
    }
  }
}

console.log(findOdd([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
```

I first add all the numbers and their occurrences in the `occurrences` object. And then I loop through the object's properties and check which one occurs odd number of times. Note that if there is more than one number that occurs odd number of times, the first one found will be returned.

Comment: This is not the only problem and I don't think your code is correct either. The OP should try to trace through it with a debugger.

Comment: This is **the problem** that causes what is asked in the title, should OP want me to find other problems, he/she should change the title of the question.

Comment: @Silidrone Also, why now returns 1 instead of 10. input [1,1,1,1,1,1,10,1,1,1,1]

Comment: What do you mean? It returns 5, not 1 or 10.

Comment: @Silidrone yes I suppose you are technically correct. But maybe at least point out that the code is still logically wrong...

Comment: @Silidrone I mean. The code must have returned 10 because it appears an odd number of times.

Comment: @ArturLuckyanenko I edited the answer with code that should solve the problem you are having. Please consider accepting/upvoting the answer if it helped you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For next comers with similar problem, it may help

```
function findOdd() {
    const data = [ 20, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4, 20, 4, -1, -2, 5 ];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
        const value = data[i];
        const tempArray = data.filter(item => item === value);
        if (tempArray.length % 2 === 1) {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```